# How to dispatch an action on BODY click in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

In my React application I need to hide an error notification on any click in the document! For this purpose I attach an event listener to body in `useEffect` hook. I successfully show the error but I can't hide it on any click, it just do not disappear. My code is:

```
const Layout = ({ children }) => {
    const [{ note: { style, text } }, dispatch] = useContext(StoreContext)

    const hideNote = () => {
        if (style) {
            console.log(`hidden`)
            dispatch(setNote({ style: ``, text: `` }))
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        document.body.addEventListener(`click`, hideNote)

        return function cleanup() {
            document.body.removeEventListener(`click`, hideNote)
        }
    }, [])

    return (
        <>
            <Note style={style} text={text} />
            <Navigation />
                {children}
            <Footer />
        </>
    );
}

export default Layout
```

Comment: This "error notification" is something like a modal thing and you want to close it on click? In that case what happens when you call `console.log('triggered')` inside your `useEffect`. But then also what do you expect the `hideNote` to do? It seem like all it does is if `style` is truthy condition it sets `style` and `text` to empty strings. What do you mean "*it can't hide on click*"?

Comment: Yes it's modal and I want to close it on click. I expect when user click somewhere in BODY then hideNote will run and if style is "someCss" then set style to empty string

Answer (score 0):

What you are missing in your code is dependency for the `useEffect`. So, we have to pass `style` as dependency of `useEffect`.

With that, when the value of `style` gets changed, we will listen events of `click` gets registered again we the updated value of style.

Without the `style` dependency, `hideNote` will have the initial value of `style` variable.

```
const Layout = ({ children }) => {
    const [{ note: { style, text } }, dispatch] = useContext(StoreContext)

    const hideNote = () => {
        // console.log("style", style) //! Check this console with and without the dependency in useEffect for better understanding
        if (style) {
            console.log(`hidden`)
            dispatch(setNote({ style: ``, text: `` }))
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        document.body.addEventListener(`click`, hideNote)

        return function cleanup() {
            document.body.removeEventListener(`click`, hideNote)
        }
    }, [style]) //! Updated Here

    return (
        <>
            <Note style={style} text={text} />
            <Navigation />
                {children}
            <Footer />
        </>
    );
}

export default Layout
```

- [Reference 1](https://codingbeautydev.com/blog/react-event-handling-common-mistakes/)
- [Reference 2](https://www.codedaily.io/tutorials/Creating-a-Reusable-Window-Event-Listener-Hook-with-useEffect-and-useCallback)